# Erro criação de arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Estou tentando criar um arquivo em C, mas não está funcionando. O sistema operacional é Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (FILE *file) { 
    file = fopen("/home/Documentos/teste.odt", "w");
    fprintf(file, "alo\n"); 
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Faça isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("/home/Documentos/teste.odt", "w");
    fprintf(file, "alo\n"); 
    fclose(file);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/OpenFile.c).

Você não pode receber um `FILE` como parâmetro no `main()`. a função `main()` pode receber apenas *strings* (ponteiros para `char`). isto não quer dizer que uma função não pode receber um `FILE`. Claro que pode, mas se for para receber este tipo, precisa receber um dado com esta informação. Ou seja você tem que criar um `FILE` em algum lugar e passar esta estrutura criada para a função que está preparada para receber este tipo de informação. O problema do `main()` é que os parâmetros dele chegam pelo sistema operacional (direta ou indiretamente) e no SO não é possível criar o tipo `FILE` e passar, ele só sabe passar *strings*.

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou!

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta quando ela resolveu seu problema postado. Além de poder votar em todas as respostas que achar que ajudaram de alguma forma. Veja como em [tour].